# Tipsy tooltip script does not work with Ajax

Tags: tipsy

I use Tipsy tooltip script on my website:

[Script homepage and examples](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)

[See the script](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js)

It displays some information on mouseover. For example, I have a page with users photos (thumbnails) and onmouseover Tipsy displays user name and age.

```
<div id="up_gus" style="display:inline-block;">
    <a href="/profile.php"><img class="west" title="username showed by Tipsy" src="/foto.jpg"/>
    </a></div
```

It works fine, but now I added Ajax/Jquery to load more photos without page refresh.

```
<div id="more"><a class="l_more" id="<?php echo $pid;?>" href="#!" >Show more</a></div>


$('.l_more').live("click",function() {
var last_msg_id = $(this).attr("id");
if(last_msg_id!='end'){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/mas.php",
data: "vid="+ last_msg_id,
beforeSend: function() {
$('a.l_more').append('<img src="../load.gif" />');
 },
success: function(html){
$("div#more").remove();
$("div#up_gus").append(html);
}
});
}
return false;
});
```

If I load more results (photos) Tipsy onmouseover does not display anything. Any ideas whi it does not work with Ajax?

Comment: wait until it's sober.